# mongodb signup with nodejs + angular2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongojs

Hello guys im new and trying to signup with  angular2 to nodejs, i have a signup page and after clicking signup, i check the email if existed or not(it can be wrong way as i sad im new)

```
router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
  var user= {
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    pass: req.body.pass
   }
  db.users.find({ email: req.body.email}).forEach(function (err, doc) {
    if (doc.email!= req.body.email) {
        db.users.save(user, function (err, usr) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(usr);
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("err", err);
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log("the email has been taken");
    }
})
```

and the error is C:\Users\project\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of null
    at C:\Users\Desktop\myTaskList\routes\user.js:58:16
58.line is if (doc.email!= req.body.email) { but i console.log them they came well from from.
i think it cause of trying 2 db process in loop but i dont know how to do it
it says the email has been taken then server stops i cant even change the email at form  i can't continue.
Thank you

Comment: Use `.findOne()` instead of `.find()` and avoid the loop. Really though you should learn about [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) instead of using `.findOne()` and `.save()`. The `.findOneAndUpdate()` method can do all of your code in one call.

Comment: thank you for fast reply i ll try it

Comment: In fact `.findOneAndUpdate({ "email": user.email },user,{ "upsert": true, "returnOriginal": false },function(err,user) { if (err) { res.send(err) } res.json(user) })`. That's it. You should probably learn [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and other update operators, but the basic statement will do as an initial replacement that works.

Comment: Thank you for all i solved it with using findOne and i had some logic mistakes now working well, only should be done  is token and i ll try it